# Ping on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, ping

I've installed Raspbian (Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)) on the Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. To be able to reach it by its hostname, I installed `winbind` and then modified the `hosts` section in the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to:

```
hosts: files dns wins
```

Unfortunately, pinging is only possible to `raspberrypi.local`, but not `raspberrypi`.

What do I have to do to make pinging without `.local` possible on Raspbian?

**EDIT**:

The `/etc/hosts` looked like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       raspberrypi
```

and I changed it to this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       raspberrypi
127.0.0.1       raspberrypi
```

But it still fails when I `ping raspberrypi` from another computer within the same network.

Comment: Why not editing host file and pointing 127.0.0.1 to raspberrypi?

Comment: @xdhe Tried this with no effect. (edit above)

Comment: how about setting up local dns-server using bind?

Comment: @xdhe How would I do that? I thought I did that with `winbind` and the `wins` entry in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that all of the edits you've done are for name resolution on the RPi itself. Other computers need to be able to find your RPi using DNS. Specifically, the DNS server they are using for name resolution. The solution is going to depend on what you're currently using for name resolution.

If your router/current dns server supports it, you can simply create a static dns mapping or alias there. That way, the other computers will obtain a response when looking for the RPi's name.

If you want a more scalable and easier to manage solution, can strongly recommend `dnsmasq` as a very flexible dhcp and dns server for exactly your situation. You configure it as your dhcp server, and configure the dhcp leases so your other computers point to the server running `dnsmasq` as their dns server. By default, `dnsmasq` will create dynamic dns entries for any machine it assigns a dhcp lease to. For example, all of my machines are assigned dhcp leases by `dnsmasq`, and point to the `dnsmasq` server for DNS. When I boot a newly-burned raspbian image, the RPi gets the same settings via dhcp, and `dnsmasq` creates a dynamic dns entry for the RPi. By default, I can locate new raspbian machines with `ping raspberrypi`, as well as every other machine that is configured to use dhcp. I can also create static dns entries in `dnsmasq` for machines that do not use dhcp.

I found `dnsmasq` setup and usage to be far simpler than using ISC DHCP and BIND.

Be aware that anytime you make changes to your dns setup, computers will cache dns entries, so it may take some time for changes to be recognized on all of your other computers.

Answer (score 0):

> But it still fails when I ping raspberrypi from another computer
>   within the same network.

Yeah it never worked because host file only translate address to ip only on raspberry. If you want to ping raspberrypi from another computer on the same network, you must setup dns-server using bind, and then point the dns-server address to the interface that your computer currently used. To configure bind, you must install bind before using

```
sudo apt-get install bind9 && cd /etc/bind
```

and then change `named.conf.local` by adding following line

```
zone "raspberrypi (or domain you like)" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.raspbeerypi";
};
```

you must note that the the ip that the raspberry currently used by using `sudo ifconfig` and then create file `db.raspberrypi` using `db.local` by copying it using
`sudo cp db.local db.raspberrypi` and then add the following line to the `db.raspberrypi`

```
;
; BIND data file for raspberrypi
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     raspberrypi. root.raspberrypi. (
                        1206201601      ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;

@       IN      NS      raspberrypi.
@       IN      A       <raspberry pi ip that it currently used>
```

the dns-server should working after you do `sudo service bind9 restart` and don't forget to appoint raspberrypi ip to the dns-server section of your OS network configuration.